# Is "average age" singular subject or plural?

Tags: verbs, verb-agreement, subjects

"The average age at which people died of heart disease are decreasing."

Can I use "is" in place of "are" ?

Comment: The averaeg  age... ***is***..., not are. The *average age* is one specific age. See usage exemples here: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20average%20age%20is%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Answer (score 2):

"Age" alone is strictly singular. "Average" alone is an adjective.

"average age" will be pertaining to one particular thing, or in this case, **a number** that is the average of a set of ages at which people died of heart disease.

So since the "average age" pertains to a single number, then it should be followed by a singular verb such as **is**.

Comment: yes, 'age' is a countable noun